# array without null

Tags: java

This code displays elements with "null" values,

```
private Objet[] tabT = new Objet[50];
/ *** /
public void affiche() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < tabT.length; i++)
            System.out.println(tabT[i]);
    }
```

My array contains only one element. Can I display an arrays' elements without "null" values and not using ArrayList?

Comment: You need to use `ArrayList`.

Comment: `if tabT[i] == null` don't print it :)

Comment: ArrayList is a wrapped array anyway.

Comment: Or, add this before print : `if(tabT[i] == null) tabT[i] = new Object[];`

Comment: I didn't print "null" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I display an arrays' elements without "null" values and not using ArrayList?

Well you can certainly conditionalize the printing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabT.length; i++)
    Object tab = tabT[i];
    if (tab != null) {
        System.out.println(tab);
    }
}
```

Note that even *with* `ArrayList` you could have null elements. However, with an array used in this way you don't really know whether an element is null because it's not "logically" part of the collection, or whether it's null because it's *deliberately* a null value within the collection. You'd be best off using `ArrayList` to keep track of that.

Using an array with more elements than you really need is basically a bad idea unless you *also* keep track of how many elements you're actually using - at which point you've basically got an `ArrayList`.

(It can be useful to do this manually in some cases, particularly for primitive arrays - but *in general* when using class types I'd use `ArrayList` instead.)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm doing an exercise about arrays, that's why :)